# SFTP Connection to Windows 2008 Server Running RemotelyAnywhere

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2008, sftp

I'm writing a program that automates a test that needs to be preformed on a regular basis. To do this test it requires a number of files to first be uploaded to a Windows 2008 Server.

The server does not allow for C$ access, and while these are test systems, it is not desirable to enable it.
The server cannot have any software installed on it.
The server has RemotelyAnywhere installed on it, which includes it's own SFTP and SSH mechanisms.

I am able to connect to the server via SSH using putty with no issue. However I am getting some trouble connecting to SFTP portion.

From the viewpoint of WinSCP:

> . 2013-10-28 13:25:07.272 Attempting keyboard-interactive
>   authentication . 2013-10-28 13:25:07.273 Prompt (6, SSH server:
>   Windows Authentication, Using keyboard-interactive authentication.,
>   Password: ) . 2013-10-28 13:25:07.273 Using stored password. .
>   2013-10-28 13:25:07.512 Access granted . 2013-10-28 13:25:07.513
>   Opened channel for session . 2013-10-28 13:25:07.712 Primary command
>   failed; attempting fallback . 2013-10-28 13:25:07.713 Server refused
>   to start a shell/command
>   * 2013-10-28 13:25:07.740 (EFatal) Server refused to start a shell/command
>   * 2013-10-28 13:25:07.740 Authentication log (see session log for details):
>   * 2013-10-28 13:25:07.740 Using username "USER".
>   * 2013-10-28 13:25:07.740 
>   * 2013-10-28 13:25:07.740 Authentication failed.

From the viewpoint of the RemotelyAnywhere Logs:

> 2013-10-28 13:24:56.525 - Info      - RemotelyAnywhere - SSH -
>   THE_HOST - Connected. 2013-10-28 13:24:57.492 - Info      -
>   RemotelyAnywhere - SSH2 - THE_HOST - SSH Port Forwarding Rules -
>   global:Enabled, user:Restricted 2013-10-28 13:24:57.492 - Info      -
>   RemotelyAnywhere - SSH2 - THE_HOST - Authenticated. 2013-10-28
>   13:24:57.679 - Info      - RemotelyAnywhere - SSH2 - THE_HOST - [3012]
>   {Read 0 SSH Port Forwarding Rule(s)} 2013-10-28 13:24:57.882 - Info
>   - RemotelyAnywhere - SSH2 - THE_HOST - [3012] {subsystem request for sftp} 2013-10-28 13:24:57.882 - Info      - RemotelyAnywhere - SSH2 -
>   THE_HOST - [3012] {subsystem request for sftp failed, subsystem not
>   found} 2013-10-28 13:24:57.882 - Info      - RemotelyAnywhere - SSH2 -
>   THE_HOST - Shell opened 2013-10-28 13:24:57.882 - Error     -
>   RemotelyAnywhere - SSH2 - THE_HOST - [3012] (error)
>   do_exec_no_pty("(null)", 1): Not allowed to execute arbitrary
>   commands. 2013-10-28 13:24:57.882 - Info      - RemotelyAnywhere -
>   SSH2 - THE_HOST - Shell closed 2013-10-28 13:24:57.882 - Info      -
>   RemotelyAnywhere - SSH2 - THE_HOST - Ended session.

Has anyone ever gotten this to work and if so what was the process? Thanks for any help you can provide.